# Obtaining a Cell Value from the a cell address which has again the cell address of the value to be found

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell, lets say B2. B2 has an address, lets say A1. The value at A1 is, lets say 5. I need to obtain this value i.e. 5 from cell B2. I have tried INDIRECT adn ADDRESS but somehow i dont seem to find a right combination. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use INDIRECT function like this:

```
=INDIRECT(B2)
```

[image]

Comment: fck...it was that easy...i was looking into much complex stuffs. Thanks man @Scott Craner